# Switch user in a init script?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, init

Here's my Init script which I have at my Ubuntu workstation. I need to run a command as another user than root, but I just can't get my head around how it should be done. Neither `sudo -u` or `su newuser` seems to work.

The script:

```
respawn
console none

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  su "anotherUser" -c ./myCommand
end script
```

Comment: use this type of command "su -c 'your command' different_user"

Comment: As @Henrick pointed out in their answer below, upstart scripts can use the [`setuid` configuration stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) to set the user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use this:

```
su -l $MUSER -c "myCommand args..."
```

**Update**: Since there is interest in this answer, I explain the way I use it here.

We run servers as normal linux users, not root. The username contains three parts:

service, customer, stage

This way we can run several services for several customers in one linux OS.

Example: foo_bar_p Service "foo" of customer "bar" and "p" means production

Here is the part of the init script. The init script can be executed as root or as foo_bar_p user:

```
# /etc/init.d/foo_bar_p-celeryd
# scriptname contains linux username  
SCRIPT_NAME=`basename "$0"`
SYSTEM=${SCRIPT_NAME%*-celeryd}

U=`id -nu`

if [ ! $U == $SYSTEM ]; then
    if [ $U == "root" ]; then
        # use "-l (login)" to delete the environment variables of the calling shell.
        exec su -l $SYSTEM -c "$0 $@"
    fi
    echo "Script must be run from $SYSTEM or root. You are '$U'"
    rc_exit 1
fi

# OK, now I am foo_bar_p
cd
. $HOME/.bashrc
....
```

Comment: What does the -l switch do??

Comment: -l | --login
A way to make the shell started a login shell.

Comment: I didn't get where the actual start of the script happens? The author said: `su -l $MUSER -c "myCommand args..."` and then he shows the script `foo_bar_p-celeryd` which checks if it was started by root or user. But how actually is determined (defined) who starts the script `foo_bar_p-celeryd`?

Comment: @beemaster the script `/etc/init.d/foo_bar_p-celeryd` is called by the system-v init. This is old unix stuff. Today I use systemd, and I am very happy with systemd. Does this answer you comment?

Answer (score 6):

For upstart, use:

```
setuid myuser
exec command args
```

Comment: Nice! Does it load .bashrc, profile and stuff like that ?

Answer (score 1):

su is probably a more universal approach, but this is also possible on some common distributions with sudo:

```
sudo -u $MUSER $COMMAND $ARGS
```

(just reread your question and didn't realize that doesn't work for you, but it has worked for me in init scripts)

Comment: Have tried this in `/etc/rc.local` but is doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04. Also tried  this: `su -l user -c /home/user/script`. Any suggestions?