# running python-daemon as non-priviliged user and keeping group-memberships

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-daemon

I'm writing a daemon in python, using the [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) package. the daemon is started at boot-time (init.d) and needs to access various devices.
the daemon is to run on an embedded system ([beaglebone](http://beagleboard.org/bone)) running ubuntu.

now my problem is that I want to run the daemon as an unprivileged user rather (e.g. `mydaemon`) than `root`.

in order to allow the daemon to access the devices I added that user to the required groups.
in the python code I use `daemon.DaemonContext(uid=uidofmydamon)`.

the process started by `root` daemonizes nicely and is owned by the correct user, but I get *permission denied* errors when trying to access the devices.
I wrote a small test application, and it seems that the process does not inherit the group-memberships of the user.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging, daemon, os

if __name__ == '__main__':
  lh=logging.StreamHandler()
  logger = logging.getLogger()
  logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
  logger.addHandler(lh)

  uid=1001 ## UID of the daemon user
  with daemon.DaemonContext(uid=uid,
                            files_preserve=[lh.stream],
                            stderr=lh.stream):
    logger.warn("UID : %s" % str(os.getuid()))
    logger.warn("groups: %s" % str(os.getgroups()))
```

when i run the above code as the user with uid=1001 i get something like

```
$ ./testdaemon.py
UID: 1001
groups: [29,107,1001]
```

whereas when I run the above code as root (or `su`), I get:

```
$ sudo ./testdaemon.py
UID: 1001
groups: [0]
```

How can I create a daemon-process started by root but with a different effective uid *and* intact group memberships?

Comment: What Linux distro is this for?

Comment: ubuntu and debian (i updated the question accordingly)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change to your daemon user before you start the python daemon? Perhaps something like (this answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941040/651848] could work for your needs?

Comment: @rkyser yes i'm doing that now (see my own answer), but it complicates a few things with file permissions (PID-files are usually created in places where only root may write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my current solution involves dropping root priviliges before starting the actual daemon, using the `chuid` argument for `start-stop-daemon`:

```
 start-stop-daemon \
      --start \
      --chuid daemonuser \
      --name testdaemon \
      --pidfile /var/run/testdaemon/test.pid \
      --startas /tmp/testdaemon.py \
     -- \
      --pidfile /var/run/testdaemon/test.pid \
      --logfile=/var/log/testdaemon/testdaemon.log
```

the drawback of this solution is, that i need to create all directories, where the daemon ought to write to (noteably `/var/run/testdaemon` and `/var/log/testdaemon`), *before* starting the actual daemon (with the proper file permissions).

i would have preferred to write that logic in python rather than bash.

for now that works, but me thinketh that this should be solveable in a more elegant fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by monkey patching the daemon module, the code is as follows:

```
import os, grp, pwd

class DaemonError(Exception):
    pass

class DaemonOSEnvironmentError(DaemonError, OSError):
    pass

def change_process_owner(uid, gid):
    try:
        # This line adds all the groups the user is member of
        # to keep the expected permissions
        os.setgroups(
            [g.gr_gid for g in grp.getgrall()
                if pwd.getpwuid(uid).pw_name in g.gr_mem
            ]
        )
        os.setgid(gid)
        os.setuid(uid)
    except Exception, exc:
        error = DaemonOSEnvironmentError(u"Unable to change process 
                    owner (%(exc)s)" % vars())
        raise error
```

And then the monkey patch:

```
import daemon
daemon.daemon.change_process_owner = change_process_owner
```